# convert image size (60x60) to other screens

Tags: java, android, image, math, image-resizing

I have an image (60x60) in a screen (768x1280) xhdpi ,

and i want to convert size of it to other screens sizes (xxhdpi , hdpi , mdpi , ldpi).

How to do this ?

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is for an **xhdpi** screen, then it must have a proper resolution of **320 dpi**.

Then in your graphic editor, set the resolution to **240 dpi** for **hdpi** and the image will be scaled down to 2/3 the original (40*40) - save it.

Then undo and set the resolution to **160 dpi**, for **mdpi** screens, and the image will scale to 1/2 the original, so it will be 30*30 - save it.

Then undo and set the resolution to **120 dpi**, for **ldpi** screens, so the image will be scaled to a value beteen 22*22 or 23*23 depending on your graphical editor's approximation (the exact value is 22.5*22.5, but pixels aren't divisible, so it must be an integer) -save it.

All these images go in a proper folder under res:

drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi